# ASP.NET MVC Binding unique radio button for list of objects in Razor @for loop, allowing only one to be selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, for-loop, razor, model-binding

I have a model as such:

```
public class ImageFileDetail {
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainImage { get; set; }
    public string SourceURL { get; set; }
}
```

I populate the razor view with a `List<ImageFileDetail>` with a count of 10, allowing the user to upload 10 images.
Only one image can be the `IsMainImage`.

[image]

I have to do it in a an `@for` loop instead of a `@foreach`, otherwise the model binder won't bind to each individual object in the list. Doing a `@foreach` gives them all the same `name=` when the form is posted, so I can't iterate it as separate objects.

View:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ImageFileDetails.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].File, new { type = "file" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].SourceURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].SourceURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @*Html.EditorFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].IsMainImage)*@
            // this is the radio button
            @Html.RadioButton("UniqueIsMainImage", Model.ImageFileDetails[i].IsMainImage)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].IsMainImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

By giving the radio button the same name in the `@RadioButton`, that allows me to only let one be selected, so that's good.  When one is selected, the prior one deselects, which is the desired result.

The problem is that on `POST`, I don't get a value of `true` for the selected radio button in the list and I'm not sure why.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By giving the radio button the name of "UniqueIsMainImage" the ModelBinder no longer associates it with the IsMainImage property

Comment: @Kei Yeah, I get that.  That's the only way I figure I could get the radio buttons to work as one group of radio buttons, rather than 10 independent radio buttons.  Trying to figure out the right way to do it without a javascript approach.

Comment: An alternate approach is to identify the main image in your Model rather than in each ImageFileDetail. For example, you could have a MainFileIndex property on your Model, which your radio button binds to. Then, the radio button can return the index of the selected file.

Comment: @Kei I'm actually playing with that thought at the moment, but I can't seem to get it to work. :/

Comment: @Kei You were right, I managed to get it with `@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.SelectedImageId, Model.ImageFileDetails[i].Id)`.  Then in my controller I can set the `bool` to `true` for the correct `Id`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the radio button to `@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.SelectedImageId, Model.ImageFileDetails[i].Id)` and pass an `Id` for each object in my list.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<ImageFileDetail> ImageFileDetails { get; set; } = new List<ImageFileDetail>();
    public int? SelectedImageId { get; set; }
}

public class ImageFileDetail {
    public int Id { get; set; } // for main image radio button
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainImage { get; set; }
    public string SourceURL { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ImageFileDetails.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].File, new { type = "file" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].SourceURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].SourceURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @*Html.EditorFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].IsMainImage)*@
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.SelectedImageId, Model.ImageFileDetails[i].Id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].IsMainImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Then in my controller, when iterating through the posted list, I set the `IsMainImage` to true for the `SelectedImageId`.

Post Controller:

```
foreach (var fileDetail in viewModel.ImageFileDetails)
{       
        if (fileDetail.Id == viewModel.SelectedImageId)
            fileDetail.IsMainImage = true;      
}
```

Thanks everyone for believing in me.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not entirely what you're looking for but in relation to your for/foreach statement - razor will actually do this for you if you let it:

Also you should be using RadioButtonFor I think.

You can leverage the templating in razor view and let it handle the list/array for you. So rather than:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails[i].SourceURL,...
```

You should be doing this (Note the name of template file should match the TYPE name):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ImageFileDetails)
```

Then create a EditorTemplates/ImageFileDetail.cshtml template:

```
@model <namespace>.ImageFileDetail

 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SourceURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SourceURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @*Html.EditorFor(x => x.IsMainImage)*@
        // this is the radio button
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsMainImage, x.IsMainImage, new { name = "UniqueIsMainImage" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.IsMainImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I get `No overload for method 'RadioButtonFor' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: @justiceorjustus I just updated there's a second param on radiobuttonfor for the selected value. As per my initial statement though - this may not be entirely what you need - it was more in reference to the for/foreach statement

Comment: Now every radio button is ticked, because they are acting as independent groups with `id`'s such as `ImageFileDetails_0__IsMainImage`and `ImageFileDetails_1__IsMainImage`, etc.  I do attest, however, that the logic in my answer + using an EditorTemplate instead would be the most proper solution, imo.

Comment: @justiceorjustus just updated again to you're original RadioButton - like I said - I'm not expecting this to be the answer - it's was just a heads-up that there's another way to handle lists/arrays in razor

Comment: @justiceorjustus can you set the name via the HtmlAttributes? doesn't matter that the IDs are different - the name attribute is what's used for grouping and sending to the server.